# Customising a DNN Module

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module

I am trying to modify a standard dnn module (Links) that comes with dnn. Essentially what i want is the make a copy of the current links module and change the look of it. I had a look inside the links module, and each link is placed in a table cell. I want to set the background of table cell to be an image and have a mouseover effect.

How can I do this? Is it possible with containers? I do not want to recode the links module functionality.

Also I want to create another type of a links module. I require this module to have a title, a sub-title (which is optional), then followed by the links. Since the tables in the original links module does not allow for a sub-title, i am thinking i have to create a new table and manage it separately. Is this the correct path to go down?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to make the changes to the table cell by editing the file /DesktopModules/Links/Links.ascx

In order to add the Sub-Title field, you would need to make a log of changes. To completely clone the module, you would need to make database changes, rename all (or most) classes used in the Link module, and make a copy of the Links folder to hold your new files. It sounds like you're going down the right path for this change.  This will require a different level of effort than simply adding a background image and an onmouseover affect on the existing links module.